# Selecting multiple columns to one string (by date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

My pricelist table looks like this:

```
   ItemCode VendorCode  UnitCost    StartingDate    
   333       362         2.31       2016-08-19 00:00:00.0
   333       362         2.16       2018-02-22 00:00:00.0
   444       362        12.96       2014-01-09 00:00:00.0   
   444       362        13.10       2015-01-09 00:00:00.0
   444       430        13.05       2017-04-01 00:00:00.0
   444       550        13.30       2018-02-01 00:00:00.0
```

I would like to have query result following:

```
   333:(362,2.16,2018-02-22)
   444:(362,13.10,2015-01-09),(430,13.05,2017-04-01),(550,13.30,2018-02-01)
```

So all different Vendors and their prices should be listed and only latest by date.
I got this far:

```
     SELECT 
     Pricelist.ItemCode + ': '+ temp.data 
     FROM Pricelist
         INNER JOIN (SELECT  p1.ItemCode,
         STUFF((SELECT '; ' + p2.VendorCode 
         FROM Pricelist p2
         WHERE p2.ItemCode = p1.ItemCode
         ORDER BY VendorCode 
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS data
         FROM Pricelist p1) as temp
     ON Pricelist.ItemCode = temp.ItemCode
     GROUP BY Pricelist.ItemCode, temp.data 
     ORDER BY 1
```

But not even close to the result I need.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: @SeanLange Looks like that link doesn't work

Comment: Moved here - https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: Can you explain the output? I think I understand but how do you enforce the order of rows? The first two 444 rows have the same date. Which one is "first"? And why are you delimiting this to multiple levels? This seems like a really bad way to handle data.

Comment: I understand that in your outuput, there is one value missing for 333, isn't it?

Comment: @ Jaime Drq: There should be only latest price by each vendor. For 333 there's two dates and always the latest (which is currently valid) should be selected.

Comment: First two 444 rows have different year. I agree, It is bad way to handle data, but that's the way it is coming to my desk.

Comment: Ok... I didn't understood well the question, let me change my answer...

Comment: Hi @Harry, I think the query now looks like what you want.

Comment: All three answers seems to work as I wanted. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` function :

```
select concat(itemcode, ':', 
       stuff( ( select top (1) with ties ',(' +concat(VendorCode, ',', UnitCost ,',', cast(StartingDate as date)) +')'
                from Pricelist
                where itemcode = p.itemcode
                order by row_number() over (partition by VendorCode order by StartingDate desc)
                for xml path('')
               ), 1, 1, ''
            ))
from Pricelist p
group by itemcode;
```

Comment: You must partition by VendorCode and ItemCode

Comment: @JaimeDrq. . . I don't think that would be required because the `subquery` has reference from the `outer query` p (`itemcode = p.itemcode`).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query:

```
create table #t (ItemCode int, VendorCode int, UnitCost decimal (10,2), StartingDate datetime)
insert into #t values
(333,362, 2.31,'2016-08-19 00:00:00.0'),
(333,362, 2.16,'2018-02-22 00:00:00.0'),
(444,362,12.96,'2014-01-09 00:00:00.0'),  
(444,362,13.10,'2015-01-09 00:00:00.0'),
(444,430,13.05,'2017-04-01 00:00:00.0'),
(444,550,13.30,'2018-02-01 00:00:00.0')

;with tr1 as (
  select
  convert(varchar(100),ItemCode) + ':' as ItemCode, 
    '(' + convert(varchar(100),VendorCode) + ',' + convert(varchar(100),UnitCost) + ',' + convert(varchar(19),StartingDate,121) + ')' as Vals,
  row_number() over (partition by ItemCode,VendorCode order by StartingDate desc) rn
  from #t
  )
select distinct ItemCode,
  stuff((
    select ',' + Vals
    from tr1 b
    where b.ItemCode=tr1.ItemCode
      and rn=1
    for xml path ('')
    ),1,1,'')
from tr1
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

First grouping the itemcodes, and then linking that to a string with the vendor details might be quite performant.

Linking those itemcodes to an OUTER APPLY with a FOR XML works well.

**For example :**

```
declare @Pricelist table (ItemCode int, VendorCode int, UnitCost decimal (10,2), StartingDate datetime)

insert into @Pricelist values
(333,362,02.31,'2016-08-19T00:01:00'),
(333,362,02.16,'2018-02-22T00:02:00'),
(444,362,12.96,'2014-01-09T00:03:00'),  
(444,362,13.10,'2015-01-09T00:04:00'),
(444,430,13.05,'2017-04-01T00:05:00'),
(444,550,13.30,'2018-02-01T00:06:00');

select concat(itemcode,':',stuff(x.details,1,1,'')) as ItemVendorDetails
from (select distinct itemcode from @Pricelist) i
outer apply 
(
    select top 1 with ties 
    concat(',(',VendorCode,',',UnitCost,',',convert(date,StartingDate),')')
    from @Pricelist p
    where p.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
    order by row_number() over (partition by ItemCode, VendorCode order by StartingDate desc)
    for xml path('')
) x(details);
```

Result:

```
ItemVendorDetails
------------------------------------------------------------------------
333:(362,2.16,2018-02-22)
444:(362,13.10,2015-01-09),(430,13.05,2017-04-01),(550,13.30,2018-02-01)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query works with the sample data provided:

```
;WITH VendorPerItemCTE AS (
   SELECT ItemCode,
          VendorCode,
          UnitCost,
          StartingDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode, VendorCode 
                             ORDER BY StartingDate DESC) AS seq
  FROM PriceList
)      
SELECT CAST(ItemCode AS VARCHAR(12)) + ':' + STUFF(ItemData , 1, 1, '')
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT p.ItemCode,
          (SELECT ', (' + CAST(VendorCode AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ' + 
                        CAST(UnitCost AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ' + 
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), StartingDate, 102 ) +
                  ')'
          FROM VendorPerItemCTE AS c
          WHERE p.ItemCode = c.ItemCode AND c.seq = 1      
          FOR XML PATH('')) AS ItemData
   FROM PriceList AS p) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/340ea/1)